# biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I'm using the [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package to add citations and a bibliography to my LaTeX document. I've noticed that only the first author plus "et al." is displayed for works with more than three authors. That's fine with me for in-text-citations, but I'd rather have the complete author information in the bibliography. How can I do that?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

#### UPDATE

Simply set the package option `maxbibnames=99` in the preamble.

```
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

There are also other options:

- `minalphanames`: the minimum number of alphabetic authors to be displayed.
- `minbibnames`: the minimum number of authors displayed in bibliography.
- `mincitenames`: the minimum number of authors displayed in citations.
- `minnames`: sets both `minbibnames` and `mincitenames`
- `maxalphanames`: the maximum number of alphabetic authors to be displayed.
- `maxbibnames`: the maximum number of authors displayed in bibliography.
- `maxcitenames`: the maximum number of authors displayed in citations.
- `maxnames`: sets both `maxbibnames` and `maxcitenames`. Default value is `3`.

#### Notes

`biblatex` 1.1, which was released on January 5th, 2011, introduced the options `maxbibnames`, `minbibnames`, `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` (settable in the document preamble and in the configuration file `biblatex.cfg`).

`biblatex` 1.6, which was released on July 29th, 2011, *"removed the local max/minnames and max/minitems options from `\printbibliography` and friends to enforce consistency. Please use the global options instead."* (Release notes)

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The maximum number of displayed authors - both for in-text-citations and the bibliography - is controlled by the option `maxnames` (with a default value of 3). To show all authors only in the bibliography, don't change the value of `maxnames` in the document preamble, but use the optional argument of `\printbibliography` instead: Type

```
\printbibliography[maxnames=99]
```

at the place in your document where you want the bibliography to appear.

If you want all bibliographies (and lists of shorthands) in all your LaTeX documents to display the complete author information, instead of typing `[maxnames=99]` every time, you can add the following code to the configuration file `biblatex.cfg`:

```
\newcounter{bibmaxnames}
\setcounter{bibmaxnames}{99}
\patchcmd{\blx@printbibliography}{#1}{#1,maxnames=\thebibmaxnames}{}{}
\patchcmd{\blx@bibbysection}{#1}{#1,maxnames=\thebibmaxnames}{}{}
\patchcmd{\blx@bibbysegment}{#1}{#1,maxnames=\thebibmaxnames}{}{}
\patchcmd{\blx@bibbycategory}{#1}{#1,maxnames=\thebibmaxnames}{}{}
\patchcmd{\blx@printshorthands}{#1}{#1,maxnames=\thebibmaxnames}{}{}
```

Note that is a hack which uses internal `biblatex` commands and hopefully will be replaced by a proper package option in a later version of `biblatex` (the current version is 0.9b). (`\patchcmd` derives from the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) package, which is loaded automatically by `biblatex`.)

Comment: +1 for coming back and updating, although I think the updates should go at the top of the post, so newcomers avoid using archaic methods.

Comment: As a member of the CTA Collaboration, 99 is not nearly enough. Same goes for Collaborations like ATLAS or CMS :D

Comment: Its so cool...And this is not working with `\fullcite'.. How to achieve that? @lockstep

Comment: If I use `maxnames` in `printbibliography`  I get the error ``Package xkeyval Error: maxnames undefined in families blx@bib2''

It works when I put this option when I `usepackage` biblatex

Answer (score 4):

Check the option `maxnames` and set it to a large value.

Comment: This changes the number of names in in-text citations as well. The correct option for *only* setting the value in the bibliography is `maxbibnames` (from page 45 of the manual). Note that if you set `maxbibnames` *before* `maxnames`, the `maxnames` setting will override the `maxbibnames` setting.