# How to force latex to abbreviate additional authors with "et al."?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I use the "ecta" bibliography style and it works fine for one exception. I have many different citations that include more than 2 authors. However, there is only one citation latex is using the names of all authors instead of abbreviating it with et al.. I use the following command:

```
\citep[p.~37]{james2013introduction}
```

And the entry in the bib-file is as follows:

```
@book{james2013introduction,
title={An Introduction to Statistical Learning},
author={James, Gareth and Witten, Daniela and Hastie, Trevor J. and Tibshirani, Robert John},
year={2013},
publisher={Springer}
}
```

And I get the following citation in the text:

```
(James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani, 2013: p. 37)
```

I tried to change the entry in the bib-file in many different ways. However, I couldn't figure out a way to solve this problem and would very much appreciate some help.

PS: The following is the exact code I am using in my file (calling the bib-file scholar):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[round,longnamesfirst,authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

This citation causes the problem: \citep[p.~37]{james2013introduction}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{scholar.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography)

Comment: @ cagirici Thanks for the comment. There is only one entry for which two authors (out of four) are equivalent. That shouldn't be a problem, right? I checked for duplicates already.

Comment: @cagirici Isn't that question about Biblatex? This one is not.

Comment: @PatrickBalada Please provide a complete minimal example. We've got (I guess) a minimal `.bib` (but you need to check that no further entries are needed) but we lack a complete example we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the comment. I added all relevant parts of my document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the `longnamesfirst` option when loading `natbib` if you don't want the names of all authors shown the first time a multiple-author piece is cited. And, since the `ecta` bibliography style uses authoryear-style citation callouts surrounded in parentheses, the `natbib` options `round` and `numberyear` are not needed either (although providing them does no harm either).

A separate comment: Don't include the substring `.bib` in the argument of `\bibliography`. I.e., write `\bibliography{scholar}` rather than `\bibliography{scholar.bib}`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{scholar.bib}
@book{james2013introduction,
   title     = {An Introduction to Statistical Learning},
   author    = {James, Gareth and Witten, Daniela and 
                Hastie, Trevor J. and Tibshirani, Robert John},
   year      = {2013},
   publisher = {Springer},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
This citation no longer causes a problem: \citep[p.~37]{james2013introduction}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{scholar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico Awesome - it worked. Thank you so much for the effort you put in!