# Source has multiple authors, but only one is listed?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How come authors go missing in my bibliography? It happens for some articles, but never for books or incollections.

[image: Authors missing for #1]

This is test.bib

```
%%% WORKS
@article{zarrinbakhsh:improving,
 author = {Zarrinbakhsh, Nima and Mohanty, Amar K. and Misra, Manjusri},
 year = {2013},
 title = {Improving the interfacial adhesion in a new renewable resource-based biocomposites from biofuel coproduct and biodegradable plastic},
 pages = {6025--6038},
 volume = {48},
 number = {17},
 journal = {Journal of Materials Science}
}

%%% DOESN'T WORK
@article{schmid:autoxidation,
 author = {Schmid, Manfred and Ritter, Axel and Grubelnik, Andreas and Zinn, Manfred},
 year = {2007},
 title = {Autoxidation of medium chain length polyhydroxyalkanoate},
 pages = {579--584},
 volume = {8},
 number = {2},
 journal = {Biomacromolecules}
}
```

This is test.tex

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    natbib=true,
    defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

    This should have more than one author~\citep{schmid:autoxidation}.

    This has more than one author~\citep{zarrinbakhsh:improving}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the options: `maxnames`, `maxbibnames`, and `maxcitenames` and the corresponding `min-` versions of the same?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864). I'm a bit confused that the style you use does not indicate omitted authors with "et al." or similar, that is a bit unusual. What style do you use? (The MWE, you will find, has "et al." after Manfred Schmid.)