# Change the bibliography style in modernCV for publications added with \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, moderncv

I have the following MWE for a CV, made using moderncv, and I need to display all the authors in the publications sections.  In other words, I need to replace the et al. with authors 2-5.

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       

\addbibresource{Downey.bib}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{start-end}{<Position Held>}{<Name of employer>}{<Place>}{<Country>}{<Description>} % arguments 3 to 6 are optional

    \nocite{bib_key}
    \printbibliography[title={Peer-Reviewed Journal articles}]

\end{document}
```

Here is the sample bibtex file.

```
@Article{bib_key,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
}
```

Comment: `maxnames=<some large number>`, e.g. `maxnames=99`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554

Comment: I tried that before but I must have had another error as it seems to be working now. opps......

Comment: Yeah, it probably is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add simple the option `maxnames=99` to `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[maxnames=99]{biblatex} % <==================================
```

That means that all your authors (up to 99) will be printed in your bibliography.

With the complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bib_key,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage[maxnames=99]{biblatex} % <==================================
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{start-end}{<Position Held>}{<Name of employer>}{<Place>}{<Country>}{<Description>} % arguments 3 to 6 are optional

    \nocite{bib_key}
    \printbibliography[title={Peer-Reviewed Journal articles}]

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]