# Displaying 3 or more authors in natbib inline citations

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I'm trying to get LaTeX to display all of the authors in the inline citations. For example,

```
\citep*{Cravino2018}
```

currently displays `(Cravino et al. 2018)`, but I would like it to display `(Cravino, Lan, and Levchenko 2018)`.

The entry in the `.bib` document is:

```
@article{Cravino2018,
author = "Cravino, Javier and Lan, Ting and Levchenko, Andrei A",
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/orcha/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Cravino, Lan, Levchenko - 2018 - Price stickiness along the income distribution and the effects of monetary policy.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {E31,E52 Keywords,Inflation,JEL Codes,consumption baskets,distributional effects,monetary policy},
title = {{Price stickiness along the income distribution and the effects of monetary policy}},
year = {2018}
}
```

I'm using `natbib` with apa style:

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

I'm not sure what is going on. The natbib documentation (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf page 9) suggests that it may have something to do with the `.bst` file, but I'm currently not using a custom `.bst` file.

I've already tried the suggestions here: [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography)

Thanks in advance!