# No 'et al.' for @collection @incollection

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have recently stopped to use @inbook to make it do what @incollection is supposed to do. However, now I have the problem that it will not show every editor -- since my bibliography preamble at this point is quite big, I am not sure if I can change it myself with the other questions concerning 'et al.'. My attempts thus far have failed... so here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{TransAlph.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references={Bibliography}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
    \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}
        {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}
        {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\providecommand*{\iflabeldateisdate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        not test {\iffieldundef{labeldatesource}}
        and 
        (test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{}} 
        or test {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{year}})}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{origdate}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
            \iflabeldateisdate
            {\iffieldnum{edition}
                {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
                    \global\clearfield{edition}}
                {}%
                \printdateextra}
            {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\newbibmacro*{origdate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    %\setunit*{\adddot}%<- comment this
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Collection{dahmen1991a,
Title                    = {Zum Stand der Ko\-di\-fi\-zie\-rung ro\-ma\-ni\-scher Klein\-spra\-chen. Ro\-ma\-nis\-ti\-sches Kol\-lo\-qui\-um\,V \textup{(Tü\-bin\-ger Bei\-trä\-ge zur Lin\-gu\-is\-tik\,348)}},
Editor                   = {Wolf\-gang Dah\-men and Ot\-to Gsell and Gün\-ter Hol\-tus and Jo\-han\-nes Kra\-mer and Mi\-cha\-el Met\-zel\-tin and Ot\-to Win\-kel\-mann},
Keywords                 = {sek},
Location                 = {Tü\-bin\-gen},
Publisher                = {Gun\-ter Narr},
Year                     = {1991}
}

@Incollection{kaislaniemi2017a,
Title                    = {`A Gra\-phic Sys\-tem which Leads its own Lin\-gu\-is\-tic Life?' Epis\-to\-la\-ry Spel\-ling in En\-glish, 1400--1800},
Author                   = {Kai\-sla\-nie\-mi, Sa\-mu\-li and Evans, Mel and Ju\-vo\-nen, Teo and Sai\-rio, An\-ni},
Booktitle                = {Säi\-ly/Nur\-mi/Pa\-lan\-der-Col\-lin/Au\-er, (eds.) (2017)},
Keywords                 = {sek},
Pages                    = {187--213},
Year                     = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Example sentence \textcite[cf.][3--6]{kaislaniemi2017a}.
Another example sentence \parencite[][39]{dahmen1991a}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much!

Edit: I would like the output to be:

> Dahmen, Wolfgang/Gsell, Otto/Holtus, Günter/Kramer, Johannes/Metzeltin, Michael/Winkelmann, Otto, (eds.) (1991): Zum Stand der Kodifizierung romanischer Kleinsprachen. Romanistisches Kolloquium V (Tübinger Beiträge zur Linguistik 348). Tübingen: Gunter Narr.
>
> Kaislaniemi, Samuli/Evans, Mel/Juvonen, Teo/Sairio, Anni (2017): “‘A Graphic System which Leads its own Linguistic Life?’ Epistolary Spelling in English, 1400–1800”. In: Säily/Nurmi/Palander-Collin/Auer, (eds.) (2017): 187–213.

with "Zum Stand der Kodifizierung romanischer Kleinsprachen. Romanistisches Kolloquium V" and "Säily/Nurmi/Palander-Collin/Auer, (eds.) (2017)" in cursive.

Comment: What exactly is the output you would like to see? Also, please make your almost-working example into a working example: It is just missing a `\documentclass` and a few other lines of code. But if the example can't be run as posted, we don't know what is *really* going on at your end.

Comment: Is it maybe just `maxbibnames=999` that you are looking for?

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you provide explicit hyphenation points for words in the bib file itself? Instead of inputting `Ko\-di\-fi\-zie\-rung`, `Epis\-to\-la\-ry`, and `Spel\-ling`, say, why don't you provide the instruction `\hyphenation{ko-di-fi-zie-rung epis-to-la-ry spel-ling}` in the preamble?

Comment: Also off-topic: Instead of `Booktitle = {Säi\-ly/Nur\-mi/Pa\-lan\-der-Col\-lin/Au\-er ...}`, give `Booktitle = {Säily\slash Nurmi\slash Palander-Collin\slash Auer ...}` a chance. `\slash` allows lines to break after the slash symbol, whereas `/` does not.

Comment: @Mico I've used \hyphenation before but it doesn't really do what I want it to (at least in the bibliography). There are  always some entries in my margins, no matter how I hyphenate
and: you are right! for everything else (mostly 'location') I use \slash -- I just overlooked it here. thanks for catching it!

Comment: @moewe you are absolutely correct. I'm happy that this problem is now gone, but I really do feeld stupid... thank you!

Comment: So we can say that this question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity:  Why would you place the names of the book's editors into the `booktitle` field (and, in the process, fail to mention the actual title of the book)?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to following @moewe's suggestion and adding the option `maxbibnames=20` (or some other suitably chosen large number) while loading `biblatex`, you should also change

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
```

to either

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}
```

or, better still,

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
```

This will allow line breaks after the `/` symbols. As @moewe points out in a comment, the second option is preferable since it allows for context-sensitive changes the the name delimiter symbol.

If you need to fine-tune the hyphenation patterns, use `\hyphenation` commands in the preamble; don't clutter the bibliographic entries with `\-` discretionary hyphenation points. In the example below, I used `\hyphenation{klein-spra-chen tü-bin-gen}` to make sure that LaTeX would perform the correct hyphenation operation on both words.

Do also consider loading the `csquotes` package and using its `\enquote` macro to "quote" material, say, the first part of the title string, in smart single-quote characters.

Last but certainly not least, you should make (much more of) a concerted effort to provide correct and usable information in the bib entries. For sure, this is how *I* would set up the two entries in question:

```
@Collection{dahmen1991a,
Title     = {Zum Stand der Kodifizierung romanischer Kleinsprachen. Romanistisches Kolloquium\,V},
series    = {Tübinger Beiträge zur Linguistik},
number    = {348},
Editor    = {Wolfgang Dahmen and Otto Gsell and Günter Holtus and Johannes Kramer and Michael Metzeltin and Otto Winkelmann},
Keywords  = {sek},
Location  = {Tübingen},
Publisher = {Gunter Narr},
Year      = {1991},
}
@Incollection{kaislaniemi2017a,
Title     = {\enquote{A Graphic System which Leads its own Linguistic Life?} Epistolary Spelling in English, 1400--1800},
Author    = {Kaislaniemi, Samuli and Evans, Mel and Juvonen, Teo and Sairio, Anni},
Editor    = {Tanja Säily and Arja Nurmi and Minna Palander-Collin and Anita Auer},
Booktitle = {Exploring Future Paths for Historical Sociolinguistics},
Series    = {Advances in Historical Sociolinguistics},
Number    = 7,
Keywords  = {sek},
Pages     = {187--213},
Year      = {2017},
Location  = {Amsterdam},
Publisher = {John Benjamins},
}
```

Note that I added the fields `series` and `number` in both entries (backfilling data as needed), and I seriously revamped the `editor` field and added an entirely new `booktitle` field for the `kaislaniemi2017a` entry.

[image]

Comment: In newer versions of `biblatex` I would prefer `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}`, but I seem to remember that the OP uses an older system where this might not work.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks! Let's wait and see if `\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}` works for the OP.

Comment: It should. The change is backwards compatible, so `\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}` will continue to work even with newer versions, but `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}` is preferable in new versions because it allows for context-sensitive changes to the delimiter.

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for this follow-up comment. I'll copy this piece of information into the body of the answer.