# Using biblatex in LyX: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, lyx

I have a follow-up question to [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=187b3c2a1a194a5f8d007792cee82e3a).

For that question, in LyX, we cannot simply write `\usepackage[maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}` in the preamble to address the problem. The reason is stated in https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex, *Using Biblatex with LyX 2.3.0 and newer*, step 5.

> In the preamble
>
> - remove `\usepackage[…]{biblatex}`
> - remove `\addbibresource{…}`
> - embrace `biblatex`-related commands with
>
>   ```
>   \AtBeginDocument{%
>     <your commands>
>   }
>   ```

Thus, we cannot use `\usepackage[maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}` in current version of LyX. Then how can we address this problem? I have worked on this for a whole day... Who would propose a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your document set up for `biblatex` already you can pass options to the package as follows.

- Go to <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd>.
- Choose *Bibliography* in the left pane.
- Under *Citation Style*, pass your options to `biblatex` by putting them into the *Options* field.

[image: The screenshot shows the "LyX: Document Settings" accessed via "Document > Settings" in the "Bibliography" pane. The "Options" field is highlighted and contains the text <code>maxbibnames=999</code>. In the background a LyX document with two example citations and a bibliography is visible.]