# BibLaTex trouble with et. al in the reference list instead of full names

Tags: biblatex

I'm having trouble with the reference list when I have many authors. In the text the reference is presented as (Svensson et. al 2019) or Svensson et. al (2019), as I want it to be. But in the reference list I also got "et. al", when I'm wanting all the names to be presented in the list instead.

Do you know how to change that?

I have the following setting: `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}`
and in the .bib file I have the names like this: 
`author={Svensson, L. and Andersson, B}`(or sometimes, but with the same problem `author={Svensson, L. and B. Andersson}`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in a single code chunk so that others can troubleshoot your issue more easily?

Comment: Off-topic: The Latin abbreviaion of "and others" is `et al.`, ***not*** `et. al`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

Using `backend=biber`  is the default for years.