# \cite maximum 2 names using maxnames=2, how to get all names appear in cross-references Bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

I want to have maximum two author name in my content, but for Bibliography will be listed all name:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxnames=2]{biblatex}
```

in:

```
@article{1testing,
  title={Title 1},
  author={Zanthony1 and rrAnthony2 and Anthony3},
  journal={Journal 1},
  volume={24},
  number={2},
  pages={258--300},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{2testing,
  title={Title 2},
  author={Zanthony1 and rrAnthony2 and Anthony3},
  journal={Journal 2},
  volume={24},
  number={2},
  pages={200--264},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

It will have:

```
The standard \verb=\cite= command produces the following output: \cite{1testing}.
```

Output below in text is correct:
[image]

However, in Bibliography, I want to listed all full name without

```
et.al.
```

[image]

Comment: Besides `maxnames` there are also the `maxbibnames` and `maxcitenames` options. Most likely, you will recieve the desired result if you replace `maxnames` with `maxcitenames`. More information can be found on page 47 of the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864