# Problem with footcite and et. al

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[12pt,halfparskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,pagetracker=true,ibidtracker=constrict, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{urlseen = {zuletzt abgerufen am}, }
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}  

\begin{document}

\footcite[53\psq]{Klett2015} 
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file

```
@Book{Klett2015,   
title =     {Lambacher Schweizer -- Mathematik Qualifikationsphase Grundkurs},   
publisher = {Ernst Klett Verlag},   
year =      {2015},   
author =    {Baum, Manfred AND Bellsted, Martin AND Brandt, Dr. Dieter AND Buck, Heidi AND Dürr, Prof. Rolf AND Freudigmann, Prof. Hans AND Greulich, Dieter AND Haug, Dr. Frieder AND Jörgens, Thomas AND Jürgensen-Engl, Thorsten AND Riemer, Dr. Wolfgang AND Sandmann, Rüdiger AND Schmitt-Hartmann, Reinhard AND Sonntag, Raphaela AND Spielmans, Heike AND Wollmann, Alexander AND Zimmermann, Dr. Peter AND Zinser, Prof. Manfred},   
address =   {Stuttgart}}
```

I've tried to make a MWE (I don't how to input only one reference without an extra file). Unfortunately only the book 'Klett2015' doesn't work with \footcite. I get this:
[image]

`maxcitenames` doesn't seem to be considered. Any ideas?
Appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue about `maxcitenames` on my system. I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SYFd.png

Comment: I get "Baum et al. 2015, pp. 53 sq." from the MWE. I guess you want `uniquelist=false`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864. Note that usually academic titles and degrees (Dr., Prof.) are not given in the `author` field. `biblatex` doesn't deal with them particularly well, either.

Comment: `style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is redundant and equivalent to the simpler `style=authoryear,`. With that style setting `sorting=nyt,` is also automatically set, so need not be given explicitly. `style=authoryear,` also sets `pagetracker=true`, so it too need not be set explicitly. Setting a value for `ibidtracker` is not really useful as the tracker will not be used by `authoryear` (it would be used with `style=authoryear-ibid,`, where `ibidtracker=constrict,` is the default).

Comment: For future reference, https://gist.github.com/moewew/45c22e5272879ac4985aef28fba4b9e0 is how I would turn your code into a fully self-contained MWE including the `.bib` file. (Plus the changes I suggested above.)

Comment: Thanks, @moewe. Although I include 'uniquelist=false' I get the same output.

Comment: Did you rerun teh full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle? If that still doesn't help, I'd like to urge you to create an MWE in the style I linked above and make sure that it reproduces the issue shown in the image before posting it here (test that in a new, empty folder).

Comment: Thanks, I have to rerun the cycle twice. Unfortunately now the authors are shorten by et al. in the bibliography either. Is this effected by `uniquelist`?

Comment: Yes. If you want all names in the bibliography, add `maxbibnames=999,` (or some other ridiculously large - or sensibly large - number, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864).

Comment: Can we say that your question was solved with `uniquelist`, so that it is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864?

Comment: Yeah, of course!