# Harvard Referencing, and how to get Latex to use et al when more then 2 authors are present

Tags: biblatex

I am complete new to using LaTeX and I am using it in Overleaf. I am trying to accomplish a more or less Harvard referencing. It works fine, but LaTeX tends to show me all the authors listed in my in-text citations, so it looks like this: (Author a, Author b, and Author c, 2000). I need it to use the abbreviation "et al." when more then 2 authors are named as authors of the same paper. How can I manage that? I do not know much about coding or such things so I need a simple explanation on how to write it, if that is possible. Thank you :) currently it looks like this:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and I use `\autocite` for in-text citation.

Comment: maxnames=2 in the biblatex options should work.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864