# Biblatex + Biber: \citeauthor needs 'and' between authors, \printbibliograpy requires '&' between authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, biber

My university is very strict on the correct formatting of the bibliography.

**When quoting in text, these are the guidelines:**

- 2 authors = familyname 1 **'en'** familyname2 year => (*Wood **en** Kroger 2000*)
- 3 authors = familyname 1 **,** familyname 2 **'en'** familyname3  year=> (*Wood **,** Kroger **en** Subtle* 2000)
- 4 authors or more =  familyname 1 **et al.** year => (*Wood **et al.** 2000*)

**In the bibliography,** for reasons unknow, we have to use **&** instead of **en**

- Wood, L. **&** R. Kroger (2000)
- Wood, L., R. Kroger **&** L. Subtle (2020)
- Wood, L., R. Kroger, L. Subtle **&** S. Else (2020)

---

**3 questions:**

1. how can I differentiate between **body = en** and **bibliography = &**.

`\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}` seems to change ALL **and**s into **&**

2. Why is my mincitenames/maxcitenames not kicking in the the MWE below.

***~~ begin edit: found this myself ~~***

3. How do I get **et al.** instead of e.a.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{%
    andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
```

***~~end edit~~***

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}               % Nederlands
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{wood_2,
  title = {2 authors},
  author = {Wood, Linda and Kroger, Rolf},
  date = {2000},
  publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},
  location = {{California}},
  langid = {english}
}

@book{wood_3,
    title = {3 authors},
    author = {Wood, Linda and Kroger, Rolf and Subtle, Loosely},
    date = {2020},
    publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},
    location = {{California}},
    langid = {english}
}

@book{wood_4,
    title = {4 authors},
    author = {Wood, Linda and Kroger, Rolf and Subtle, Loosely and Else, Somebody},
    date = {2020},
    publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},
    location = {{California}},
    langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[innamebeforetitle=true,
            citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp,  % meerdere auteurs = chronologisch maar gegroepereerd per auteur
            bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
%           style=ext-authoryear-comp,      % meerdere auteurs = chronologisch maar gegroepereerd per auteur
            sortcites,                      % sorteer citaties per jaar,
            sorting=ynt,
            mincitenames=1,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=99,                 % Toon alle auteurs van een boek - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography
            uniquename=init,
            giveninits=true,                % initialen bij voornaam
            doi=false,                      % geen DOI
            isbn=false,                     % geen ISBN
            dashed=false,                   % auteurs moeten altijd voluit geschreven worden, hoe vaak ze ook geciteerd worden
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\begin{document}

2 authors: \citeauthor{wood_2} - \autocite{wood_2}

3 authors: \citeauthor{wood_3} - \autocite{wood_3}

4 authors: \citeauthor{wood_4} - \citeauthor*{wood_4} - \autocite{wood_4}

    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Not that it matters, but `citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp, bibstyle=ext-authoryear,` is equivalent to the shorter and easier to parse `style=ext-authoryear-comp,`. The double braces in both `publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},` and `location = {{California}},` are superfluous and can be replaced by single brace pairs: `publisher = {SAGE Publications}, location = {California},`.

Comment: @moewe i appreciate such help! As you can see, I had ``style=`` commented out because I thought it may affected the ``maxcitenames`` for some reason...

Comment: the double braces are put there by zotero. I have no idea why it sometimes uses single pairs and sometimes double pairs...

Comment: Theoretically, `style`s can affect `(min|max)(bib|cite)names` settings, but the options *you* pass to `biblatex` about that will take precedence. So in your setting that's nothing to worry about. But as I said, `citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp, bibstyle=ext-authoryear,` and `style=ext-authoryear-comp,` are equivalent, so the risk is the same no matter if you take the more opaque long version of setting `bibstyle` and `citestyle` separately or the shorter `style`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following `\DeclareDelimFormat` commands:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[]{finalnamedelim}{\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{3}{\addspace\&\space}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

To get the 4 authors in this example to be truncated, you need to add `uniquelist=false` to the load options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}               % Nederlands
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{wood_2,
  title = {2 authors},
  author = {Wood, Linda and Kroger, Rolf},
  date = {2000},
  publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},
  location = {{California}},
  langid = {english}
}

@book{wood_3,
    title = {3 authors},
    author = {Wood, Linda and Kroger, Rolf and Subtle, Loosely},
    date = {2020},
    publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},
    location = {{California}},
    langid = {english}
}

@book{wood_4,
    title = {4 authors},
    author = {Wood, Linda and Kroger, Rolf and Subtle, Loosely and Else, Somebody},
    date = {2020},
    publisher = {{SAGE Publications}},
    location = {{California}},
    langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[innamebeforetitle=true,
            citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp,  % meerdere auteurs = chronologisch maar gegroepereerd per auteur
            bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
%           style=ext-authoryear-comp,      % meerdere auteurs = chronologisch maar gegroepereerd per auteur
            sortcites,                      % sorteer citaties per jaar,
            sorting=ynt,
            mincitenames=1,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=99,                 % Toon alle auteurs van een boek - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography
            uniquename=init,
            uniquelist=false,
            giveninits=true,                % initialen bij voornaam
            doi=false,                      % geen DOI
            isbn=false,                     % geen ISBN
            dashed=false,                   % auteurs moeten altijd voluit geschreven worden, hoe vaak ze ook geciteerd worden
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[]{finalnamedelim}{\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{3}{\addspace\&\space}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}%


\begin{document}

2 authors: \citeauthor{wood_2} - \autocite{wood_2}

3 authors: \citeauthor{wood_3} - \autocite{wood_3}

4 authors: \citeauthor{wood_4} - \citeauthor*{wood_4} - \autocite{wood_4}

    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Could you explain ``\DeclareDelimFormat[]{finalnamedelim}{\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{3}{\addspace\&\space}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}%`` - Because ``\DeclareDelimFormat[]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}`` seems to work for me..?

Comment: Actually, with `uniquename=false` I guess it's no longer needed. Without that option set, it puts `&` in 4 authors or more when they get expanded by `uniquelist`.  It doesn't do harm, so I'll leave it in the answer.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce a situation where the `\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{3}` is needed with this MWE. Since I firmly believe it shouldn't be needed, I would  consider that a bug here. Can you open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues or send me an MWE via email ([can be found in the `biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf)), please?

Comment: @moewe Yes, I'll do that in a day or so (end of term).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I bother you about this again? I played around with the MWE a bit more, but still I couldn't find an example where the `\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{3}` would be needed.

Comment: @moewe I've sent you mail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I see what this was about. I thought the question asked about having "en" in citations and "&" in the bibliography (regardless of the number of authors), but the conditional implements a more complex scheme. No bug to worry about.