# Lyx Biblatex (natbib mode) showing only first author's name in the Reference section

Tags: biblatex, lyx, natbib, layout

I am using Lyx Biblatex (natbib mode). And in the reference section, it's only showing only first author's name and all others are hidden in **et al.** That's fine in the text part of the paper. But all names should be shown in Reference section. How can I show everyone?

Comment: Make a new document, and add  only one (1) cite from one (1) of the available example datababases (not your .bib file). THen configure natbib, and check that the problem is also here. If this happens, export to LateX an edit your question to paste the **whole** LaTeX code. If the problem is solved in the new file, just compare the LaTeX codes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864) you will want to set the option `maxbibnames=999,` (or some other very high value) to typeset all names in the bibliography. For example

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
```

If you are using LyX, you normally don't load `biblatex` yourself, you have LyX load the package for you, in which case you can set the option in **Document > Settings... > Bibliography** under **Options**

[image: The settings dialogue window with maxbibnames=999,]