# Lyx in text citation giving two author names before et al., rather than one

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx

I'm using Lyx 2.3.2 and biblatex for my PhD thesis and I keep coming up against a strange issue with some in text citations. I am using author year format, which for references with more than two authors should give the citation (author1 et al., year). However, for two of my references I am getting (author1, author2 et al., year).

The only thing I have been able to find out is that lyx would normally do this if just having the author and year could cause confusion due tohaving two citations that are the same, but refer to different references (i.e [Author1, AuthorX et al., 1999], [Author1, AuthorY et al,. 1999]). However, in my instance this is not the case.

I have looked through the associated Bib file and found nothing out of the ordinary, I have tried various different author, year reference styles, and I have deleted the two references from my computer and added them back into my reference manager. Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? The only other thing I can think of is if the papers had dual first authorship, but as far as I am aware this isn't the case either.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the bib for the two references:

```
@article{Hodgson2012,
author = {Hodgson, Jenny A. and Thomas, Chris D. and Dytham, Calvin and Travis, Justin M.J. and Cornell, Stephen J.},
doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0047141},
editor = {Getz, Wayne M.}
issn = {19326203},
journal = {PLoS ONE},
keywords = {Climate change,Conservation science,Electric conductivity,Extinction risk,Fractals,Habitats,Species colonization,Species extinction},
month = {oct},
number = {10},
pages = {e47141},
pmid = {23082145},
publisher = {Public Library of Science},
title = {{The Speed of Range Shifts in Fragmented Landscapes}},
volume = {7},
year = {2012}
}
@article{Hodgson2016,
author = {Hodgson, Jenny A. and Wallis, David W. and Krishna, Ritesh and Cornell, Stephen J.},
doi = {10.1111/2041-210X.12614},
isbn = {2041-210X},
issn = {2041210X},
journal = {Methods in Ecology and Evolution},
keywords = {circuit theory,climate change,dispersal,ecological restoration,indicators,invasion,networks,optimisation,reserve design,systematic conservation planning},
number = {12},
pages = {1558--1566},
title = {{How to manipulate landscapes to improve the potential for range expansion}},
volume = {7},
year = {2016}
}
```

Comment: normally it happens because the author is needed to make a list unique. But without code and the bib it is quite impossible to tell you why it happens in your case. But the year doesn't matter. biblatex will add the author also if you have one with another year.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I have just added the bib text for the two documents, I hope that helps. The two references do have the same first author so could that be the reason?

Comment: yes, biblatex will by default use a second author here. You can change that with an option (normally, it can depend on the style you are using).

Comment: You want the option `uniquelist=false`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864. In case you need help with adding `biblatex` options in LyX, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562432/35864 (where it is explained for `maxbibnames=999,`).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I'll have a look into it.

Comment: @moewe if you would like to add your comment as an answer I will accept it, as that fixed my problem.

Comment: Would you also be OK with closing the question as a duplicate of the `uniquelist=false` question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864)? Or do you want a separate answer because of LyX?