# How to display at most 3 authors names in one \cite?

Tags: citing, natbib

update with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep*{example1,example2}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mylist}
\end{document}
```

My bib list:

```
@article{example1,
  title={Title of example one},
  author={last1, first1 and last2, first2 and last3, first3},
  journal={Journal 1},
  number={123},
  year={2020}
}
@article{example2,
  title={Title of example two},
  author={last4, first4 and last5, first5 and last6, first6 and last7, first7},
  journal={Journal 2},
  number={234},
  year={2021}
}
```

The output is:

> (last1, last2, and last3, 2020; last4, last5, last6, and last7, 2021)

---

I cite two papers in one command: `\citep{paper1,paper2}`. Paper1 has 3 authors, and paper2 has 4 authors. Is there a way to display all 3 names for paper one, but display `authorA et al.` for paper2?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWEB) of your current code for us to work on.

Comment: Depending on your bibliography style, you are most likely looking for the options: `mincitenames` and `maxcitenames`. Or, if you want this to be consistent with your bibliography entries: `minnames` and `maxnames`.

Comment: I have my doubts that you are really using BibLaTeX. The reason is, that `\citep{}` and `\citet{}` are available there only via the natbib-option, but the proper BibLaTeX commands would be `textcite{}` and `\parencite{}`. It could still be that you are using BibLaTeX with natbib-compatability, but I would guess you probably use BibTeX with the `\usepackage{natbib}`. Depending on what is correct, the solution for your problem will be **very** different.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you want to set the number of names printed only for one particular entry or for all entries with the same number of authors. In the latter case, `(max|min)(cite|bib)names` is the right way to go, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864. But note that those values can be overruled by the `uniquelist` option (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864). If you are looking to show a particular number of names for a specific entry only, other ideas are needed.

Comment: I just realised that you asked a similar question before (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558055/35864). At the time I commented that a solution depends on many factors that you need to tell us about. I linked to pages explaining how you can create a helpful example document. Please follow that advice and tell us more about your current citation setup.

Comment: My apologies for forgetting that I struggled with the same problem months ago, as @moewe points out. I added a MWE. I was indeed using `natbib`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a truncated author list when using the `natbib` citation management package and the `chicago` bibliography style, you shouldn't use the `\citep*` and `\citet*` commands -- which, by design, show *all* authors in the citation callout. Hence, if you change `\citep*{example2}` to

```
\citep{example2}
```

you're all set in terms of generating a truncated parenthesis-style citation call-out.

If, for some reason, you need to show a citation call-out to both entries in a single parenthetis-style citation command, you could write

```
(\citealp*{example1}; \citealp{example2})
```

Hopefully, your document doesn't feature too many of these odd-ball cases...