# Citation and Bibliography Formatting with Biblatex - "et al."

Tags: formatting, citing, multiple-citations

Many of the things I've tried on previous threads have thus far not worked. Therefore, if anyone could help with this formatting issue in Biblatex, it would be greatly appreciated.

My issue is two-fold:

(1) I would like the in-text reference to be a single author year. Therefore, max = 1 authors followed by "et al." and the year.

(2) However, in the bibliography, I would like all authors to be included.

Here's what I've tried so far, but with no success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle = authoryear, backend = biber, natbib = true, maxbibnames=1]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    andothers = {et al\adddot}
}
\addbibresource{Ref.bib}
\bibliography{biblio}

% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{parkin2016determines}
\printbibliography
```

```
#BIB FILE

@article{parkin2016determines,
    title={What determines the shape of an EQ-5D index distribution?},
    author={Parkin, David and Devlin, Nancy and Feng, Yan},
    journal={Medical Decision Making},
    volume={36},
    number={8},
    pages={941--951},
    year={2016},
    publisher={SAGE Publications Sage CA: Los Angeles, CA}
}
```

Comment: `maxcitenames` controls the citation, `maxbibnames` the bibliography, you want `maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=99` (or however large a number you need), see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1557/106162).

Comment: Hi @DaiBowen. That's very helpful - I had overlooked that argument beforehand. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi@DaiBowen. As it stands, I get the bibliography as needed given your arguments above. However, my in-text citation reads as Parkin et al., 2016. Do you know how to place the year of the citation in parenthesis such that it reads Parkin et al. (2016)?

Comment: Got it, sorry: [natbib]{biblatex} followed by \citet. Thanks again for your help earlier