# configuration of citation and bibliography style based on biblatex-extend package

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am quite new to latex and want to create my own style for citation and bibliography. Although I have read some package documents and source codes regarding this question, I still couldn't find a satisfactory way. To clarify my problems, I provide a MWE using the extended biblatex package as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[sorting=nyt, backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-comp, introcite=label]{biblatex}
% self-define cite and bibliography style based on biblatex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareCiteCommand{parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\textsc{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\setlength{\introcitewidth}{15\biblabelsep}
% end of self-define cite and bibliography style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
    @article{Holger1993,
    author={Holger,Manuel and Schumacher,Thomas and Herbes Beltran},
    title={The development of NDT},
    year={1993}
}

    @article{Marx1995,
    author={Marx,Anders and Vogel,Enrico},
    title={Scientific research of timber},
    year={1995}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    Here is an example \autocite{Holger1993}, \autocite{Marx1995}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So the above MWE will generate follow:
[image]

As you may observed, I extended manually the labelwidth to separate the label and the entry. But it may result in very restricted space for the bibliography entry as shown in the first example. What I expect is actually to create an abbreviation for the label with only the family name of the first author and the year, i.e. [Holger et al. 1993] for the first example. And that should also be done for the citation style. So instead [Holger, Schumacher, and Beltran 1993], I expect [Holger et al. 1993] for the first citation.

Could someone give me some ideas?

Comment: Play around with `maxcitenames`, `mincitenames`, `maxbibnames` and `minbibnames`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864.

Comment: @moewe thanks i will try.

Comment: @moewe i tried to set maxcitenames=1, and maxbibnames=99, it works fine for citations with more than 3 authors. Only the family name of the first author will be displayed. But if the citation has 2 authors, both of them are displayed. But I set maxcitenames=1.

Comment: If I set `maxcitenames=1` in your example document I get "[Holger et al. 1993], [Marx et al. 1995]" so "First author + et al." for both works with three and two authors. If that isn't the case in your actual, bigger document you probably hit the `uniquelist` feature (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864).

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your help! I find the part introducing uniquelist and uniquename in the biblatex document. Problem solved.